# php send value of 0 using $_GET variable

Tags: php

How can i pass a `$_GET` variable value of `'0'` while checking if it exists?
For example I normally check to see is the variable exists by: 
`$myVar= (!isset($_GET['t1'])? $_GET['t1'] : '');`  
or  
`$myVar= (!empty($_GET['t1'])? $_GET['t1'] : '');` 
but either both of these checks return `false`

Comment: https://eval.in/189157

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first line isn't doing what you expect, because it's asking: is `$_GET['t1']` not set? If it's not, `$myvar = $_GET['t1']`. If it is set, `$myvar = ''`.

`$myVar= (!isset($_GET['t1'])? $_GET['t1'] : '');`

So it should be:

`$myVar= (isset($_GET['t1'])? $_GET['t1'] : '');`

Comment: And zero is considered to be empty, so `!empty($_GET['t1'])` doesn't pass either http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php